# How to have sign-in open different window and get access token back

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redirect, google-chrome-extension, shopify-app

I am working on a chrome extension, and when a user creates an account within the extension, I want a separate tab to open up to allow the user to download a Shopify app, and once the app is downloaded that tab should close and the user should be authenticated within the extension. Opening a separate tab for the Shopify app install is trivial, but once that is done, how do I get the access token from the other tab into my chrome extension so that the user is authenticated there? Can I use a webhook for this? How are these types of authentications usually done, where the authentication is done in a separate window?

Basically, how do I get the access token that is returned in the second tab into my chrome extension so that the user can then use it to make api requests?

Comment: You are probably talking about Oauth / Access Delegation. The very basic idea behind the authentication style you are describing is that you'd send a "forward" or "callback" url with your redirect request to some url like `https://example.com/login?afterLoginUrl=https://your_site.xyz/post_login` that way the other site knows where to redirect (and with some token if you so wish)